# Connecting to Oracle with c# framework 3.5

Tags: c#, oracle

I am writing a sharepoint webservice for inserting and retrieving data from oracle database in some other servers.Since system.Data.OracleClient is deprecated we have to use oracle.dataaccess dll for connecting to oracle database. But this can only be achieved by using the dependency dlls. How can i achieve this for connecting my sharepoint service to oracle database. Please help!!!!

Comment: you might want to try connecting to the database using `EnterpriseLibrary Data Access Block` and in connection string use `providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"`

Comment: You're using .NET 3.5 in 2015. Why do you care about deprecated `OracleClient`, out of all things? :)

Comment: I want to use it with sharepoint 2010. so i have to deal with this 3.5 framework

Comment: We don't say. NET Framework 3.5 is out of date, it is System.Data.Oracleclient which is deprecated for years!

Answer (score -1):

DevArt dotConnect for Oracle had a managed (client agnostic) driver for Oracle well prior to .NET 3.5:

https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/

I'm a big fan of Dev Art's driver, but it does cost money.  It's pennies on the dollar for the headaches it spares you, however.  They do have a free version.  I've never tried it, but you may want to check it out.

You've probably already looked into Oracle's managed ODP.net -- I'm pretty sure that requires 4.0, so you're out of luck with that one.